# How to filter using FHIR Identifiers from C# to mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, hl7-fhir

I'm using C#, HL7.Fhir.R4 and mongo Driver to manage mongoDB, the FHIR resources are stored in mongo DB, the resources have a property to identify the resource, this property is an array, so it can store multiple identifiers, when we are querying to get some resource, mongo retrieves some resources when are used multiple filters.

Part of the resource

```
{
    "SerializedResource": {
        "resourceType": "ServiceRequest",
        ...
        "identifier": [
            {
                "use": "official",
                "system": "mySystem",
                "value": "value1"
            },
            {
                "use": "usual",
                "type": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "myCodeSystem",
                            "code": "myCode"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "system": "mySystem",
                "value": "value2"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

if we filter by use=official and value=value2, mongo is retrieving this resource, because is fulfilled by the resource but in two different identifiers.

the filters are implemented like:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filters = new List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>();
...
filters.Add(builder.Eq("SerializedResource.identifier.use", "official"));
filters.Add(builder.Regex("SerializedResource.identifier.value", $"/^value2$/i"));
```

How can I filter both properties in the same identifier?
thanks in advance

We have found that in mongo we can filter using

```
{"SerializedResource.identifier":{ $elemMatch: {"use":"official", "value":/^value2$/i}}}
```

but we can not found a way to execute from c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with [`ElemMatch`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_ElemMatch__1.htm).

```cs
var filter = builder.ElemMatch("SerializedResource.identifier",
    builder.Eq("use", "official")
    & builder.Regex("value", $"/^value2$/i"));
```

Note that, the query above will filter the document containing `SerializedResource.identifier` array with the nested document that must match **both** `use` and `value` field at the same time.

While your current query will filter the document containing `SerializedResource.identifier` array with the nested document that must match **either** `use` or `value` field but doesn't guarantee must be matched for both fields in the nested document.